# How to extract words ending with ed and the words after and before it in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a column of ingredients and i want to extract all those ingredients that end with "ed" . e.g; i have a list of ingredients like:

```
Dolin dry vermouth
Cabin Fever maple flavored whiskey
bacon strips
ginger ale
tequila
Eggnog*
Flamed orange peel
Amontillado sherry
White rum
Lemon wedge
Vodka
Fresh lemon juice
Triple sec
Silver tequila
Gin
Simple syrup
Cola, to top
Cola Candied ginger
Fresh lemon juice
```

I want a regex which should extract complete string of ingredient ending with "ed" like:

```
Cabin Fever maple flavored whiskey
Flamed orange peel
Cola Candied ginger
```

Comment: `.*ed |$`, `.*ed( .*)$` and so on - depends on the precise task.

Comment: If I want the remaining ingredients to be extracted in ingredients column other than words ending with "ed" .....then what would be the regexp?

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern `[a-z]ed( |$)` with [`regexp`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/) operator/function.

Pattern explanation:

`[a-z]` - match any letter

`ed` - match `ed` literally

`( |$)` - match space or end of string (so make sure it's not followed by any letters)

Full query would be:

```
select * 
from test
where lower(ingr) regexp '[a-z]ed( |$)'
```

[SQL demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kLjiFLD8AUq8Qg99mikSv5/0)

Note that I added record `Orange flamed` to show it working when `ed` is at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ingredients i WHERE i.name LIKE ('%ed %') OR i.name LIKE ('%ed');
```

The output you are expecting would require two conditions

1. LIKE ('%ed %') :- this will give result set where ed is coming in between text like Cabin Fever maple flavored whiskey
   Flamed orange peel
   Cola Candied ginger
2. LIKE ('%ed') :- this will give the filtered result having ed as suffix in string like  Cotton Candy flavored

Comment: Thanks for this query....I want to further ask that if i want only the word ending with "ed"?....like i wanted to get "flavored"....then what regex should I use?

Comment: Are you asking that you want only those strings which end with "ed" For ex string like "Cotton Candy flavored"?

Comment: i just want that word which ends with ed